# How can I ensure change detection runs when field is not marked as dirty?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I am using the amazing time picker. I have a form array that is nested within a form group. The amazing time picker works well and updates the target form field. The problem is that the value never gets updated in the form model data. I inspected the code and the field never gets marked as dirty. The form values get updated when I change the time input field with the arrows, but not with the atp dialog.

I have tried several ways to programmatically mark the field as dirty to trigger the Angular change detection and have not been successful yet. I have tried the markForDirty method on several levels of the form. Nothing has worked. Ideally, I would like to trigger it for the event.target field only.

```
// Here is my form structure
this.timestampForm = new FormGroup( {
  timestamps: new FormArray( [ this.buildTimestamps() ] )
} );
// Here is the buildTimeStamps method
buildTimestamps (): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup( {
      id: new FormControl( '0' ),
      timecardDetailsId: new FormControl( '0' ),
      workDate: new FormControl( '' ),
      startTime: new FormControl( '' ),
      endTime: new FormControl( '' )
    } );
  }
// Here is the template field with which I am working...
<input
    name="startTime"
    id="{{ startTime + i }}"
    class="form-control"
    atp-time-picker
    type="time"
    #startTime
    (click)="open($event)"
    formControlName="startTime"
/>
// Here is the open method...
open ( event: any ) {
    const amazingTimePicker = this.atp.open();
    amazingTimePicker.afterClose().subscribe( time => {
      event.target.value = time;
      event.target.focus();// I added this because the closing of the dialog box did not return focus to the target
    } );
  }
// Here is the json output of the form...
{
  "timestamps": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "timecardDetailsId": "0",
      "workDate": "",
      "startTime": "", // I am focusing on this property currently
      "endTime": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Ideally, I just want the closing of the atp dialog to return the time (which it already does) and update the form data. So if I select 08:00 in the atp modal, then I expect the form field to display 08:00 and the startTime property to display "08:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out. Here is my answer...

```
open ( event: any ) {
    //  Open timepicker
    const amazingTimePicker = this.atp.open();
    // Observable to listen for closing of dialog
    amazingTimePicker.afterClose().subscribe( time => {
      // Grab event target id
      let eventId = event.target.id;
      // Parse id number from dynamic form array
      eventId = eventId.slice(eventId.indexOf(']') + 1);
      // Set target value equal to time from timepicker dialog
      event.target.value = time;
      // Grab all timestamps as array to be able to loop through and use key
      const timestampsFormArray = this.timestampForm.get( 'timestamps' ) as FormArray;
      // Check to see if the target is start time
      if(event.target.name === 'startTime') {
        // Loop over timestamps array
        timestampsFormArray.controls.forEach( (currentTarget, key) => {
          // If event id number is equal to timestamp array key,
          // set current target equal to time from timepicker dialog
          // Update form model
          if (eventId == key) {
            currentTarget[ 'controls' ].startTime.value = time;
            currentTarget[ 'controls' ].startTime.updateValueAndValidity();
          }
        } );
      }
      // Check to see if the target is end time
      if(event.target.name === 'endTime')  {
        // Loop over timestamps array
        timestampsFormArray.controls.forEach( (currentTarget, key) => {
          // If event id number is equal to timestamp array key,
          // set current target equal to time from timepicker dialog
          // Update form model
          if (eventId == key) {
            currentTarget[ 'controls' ].endTime.value = time;
            currentTarget[ 'controls' ].endTime.updateValueAndValidity();
          }
        } );
      }
      // Reset focus on original event target
      event.target.focus();
    } );
  }
```

Hopefully it will help others. Feel free to critique.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the Value call `formControl.updateValueAndValidatity()` this should work.

I never used FormArray befor but according to my research it should work like this:

You get the Element inside a FormGroup with `formGroup.controls[key]`
And the Element inside a FormArray you get with `formArray.controls[index]`

So in your case it should be `timestampForm.controls[‚timestamps‘].controls[0].controls[‚key of the contol wher you want to set the value‘]`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that and received the following error...

event.target.updateValueAndValidity is not a function

Comment: Okay try to adress the FormControl where you want to display the time and there try ´updateValueAndValidity()´

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how to do that? I tried to utilize forEach on my timestamps array and it balked at that.